# Can I add a label to a single tool in a wxPython toolbar?

Tags: python, wxpython

Does anyone know if it's possible to add a label to a single tool in a wx.ToolBar? I've found a global setting but no option to set it for a single tool.

Comment: Small update: I discovered I can do it (in GTK at least) by mixing the old AddTool() and new AddLabelTool() methods. The results are still messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that's a limitation of the native widget. It's an all or nothing affair. You could make the label a part of the image on the tool item though. Or you might be able to do it with FlatMenu which has a Toolbar widget equivalent that's written in pure Python, so you can hack it. See the wxPython demo for an example of its API.

Comment: Not sure about windows but I'm pretty sure GTK can do it: Gedit has a label in its toolbar for "Open"

Comment: Yeah, it may just be an OS thing too. Some of this gets complicated. Which is why I mentioned FlatMenu. It's pure Python and should theoretically look the same on all systems.

Comment: Oh well. I'll settle for a label free toolbar then. Thanks!